# OR (||) operator in angular.forEach not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following json array, and need to remove some of them by certain conditions:

```
var data = [
             {data1: "aaa", data2: "bbb", data3: "ccc"},  // First
             {data1: "ddd", data2: "eee", data3: "fff"},  // Second
             {data1: "ggg", data2: "hhh", data3: "iii"},  // Third
             {data1: "jjj", data2: "eee", data3: "lll"}   // Fourth
           ];
angular.forEach(data, (item, i) => {
  if (item.data2 == 'eee' || item.data3 == 'iii') {
    data.splice(i, 1);
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

In the above case, I need to remove second (data2 has "eee"), third (data3 has "iii"), and fourth (data2 is "eee") object from the data array.
However, the third object is not spliced and remains in data array.

Could I use OR (||) operator in this manner? If not, what is the proper way to remove elements from array using multiple conditions?

I've been scratching my head around for hours with this problem, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Comment: The problem is not with the `||` operator: Don't use `splice` from inside a loop.

Comment: Don't change the array you're iterating over, better use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: The problem when remove a item when iterating is that size changes and index will have behaviours that you don't want. The solution is to loop reverse: https://jsfiddle.net/joherro3/pca5Lbgg/1/ But better use filter.

Comment: I deleted my original answer and posted a more complete solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use filter instead,
When using splice you change the array you want to iterate on which is a no no:

```
var data = [
             {data1: "aaa", data2: "bbb", data3: "ccc"},  // First
             {data1: "ddd", data2: "eee", data3: "fff"},  // Second
             {data1: "ggg", data2: "hhh", data3: "iii"},  // Third
             {data1: "jjj", data2: "eee", data3: "lll"}   // Fourth
           ];
var filtered = data.filter(function (element) {
    return element.data2 !== 'eee' && element.data3 !== 'iii';
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Up vote for being the right answer but you should explain why splice wont work.

Comment: What a quick, beautiful one. I never thought my problem was answered so quickly! Thank you all for quick insights!! And thanks @korven and j3ff for great answer!!

Comment: @Köttur So you wanted a quick solution as opposed to an answer that addressed your problem specifically and explained what was wrong with your code...?

Comment: @8protons Actually I've read your detailed explanation... And yes, I firstly thought that the OR operator is working when I've been inspecting the console output... Now I understand why splice(i, n) won't work. I just thought it would simply remove the "n" element in index "i". I should have read the docs more carefully.

Comment: @Köttur if you looop in the array from last element to the first element, index will not affect to the next element. That's the solution why you didn't get your code working as expected. The answers are better approachs to handle your problem.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Thank you for advice!! And your solution is quite interesting. I'd like to try your approach once get back to office. Thanks!!

Comment: @Köttur Well you shouldn't accept answers too quickly, especially ones that do not fit the full requirements of addressing your confusion. Giving you a solution and a solution alone without event attempting to explain _why_ you're code doesn't work isn't part of the Stack Overflow theme of _teaching_ and _explaining_. Anyways, I posted a solution and explanation. Give mine a read and good luck.

Comment: @8protons Well I never thought the problem was actually solved this quickly, and I'm ashamed my self didn't know such a fundamental feature of Angular (filter)... So I thought it's time to research and understand why the solutions works.
Anyway, thanks to your detailed explanation, I finally understand how thesse piece of codes works, and I've leaned a lot than just reading docs and solutions alone. Thanks again!!
And yes, everyones too quick as I can't thank you enough for all who gave me good insights and solutions :P

Comment: @Köttur Good! I'm glad that you learned :] That's all I was wanting, alongside an answer that would help others in your same position to learn as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` instead of `splice`.

`splice` relates on the index of the item therefore when you remove item in the loop the index number become invalid.

```js
var data = [
             {data1: "aaa", data2: "bbb", data3: "ccc"},  // First
             {data1: "ddd", data2: "eee", data3: "fff"},  // Second
             {data1: "ggg", data2: "hhh", data3: "iii"},  // Third
             {data1: "jjj", data2: "eee", data3: "lll"}   // Fourth
           ];

function keepItemCondition(item) {
  return !(item.data2 == 'eee' || item.data3 == 'iii');
}

var filtered = data.filter(keepItemCondition);

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you @j3ff for great answer!!

Answer (score 0):

When checking the output in console, you'll see that what is being returned is an array:

```
[Object, Object]
```

which containts

```
[{'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}, {'ggg', 'hhh', 'iii'}]
```

Which tells us that your code is deleting the 2nd and 4th array objects. As proof, comment out your `foreach` routine to find that the integrity of the original array is preserved.

Why? Well, you're logical **OR ( || )** operator is working as expected!

```
angular.forEach(data, (item, i) => {
  if (item.data2 == 'eee' || item.data3 == 'iii') {
    data.splice(i, 1);
  }
});
```

When the object item `data2 == 'eee'` or `data3 == 'iii'` in the current object being inspected, your code says to splice (*in other words, remove*) the elements starting at `i` and ending at `i` in the `data` array. This is expressed by the fact that you wrote `splice(i, 1)`; had you written something like `splice(i, 3)`, for example, you'd remove the object elements starting at `i` and ending at `i+2`. Another way to look at is by saying, "`splice(i, n)` means to remove `n` elements starting at index `i`".

So each time your comparison expression is evaluated, you're commanding that the current element `i` and *only* `1` *element from* `i` (which is `i` itself) be removed from the `data` array; that current element happens to be the **objects** that contain `eee` and `iii`. Run through your loop if you must, counting `i` to prove it to yourself that `data[1]` and `data[3]` are being removed.

If you're asking how to remove the specific items of the objects when item `data2 == eee` or item `data3 == iii`, consider the following:

```
var data = [
             {data1: "aaa", data2: "bbb", data3: "ccc"},  // First
             {data1: "ddd", data2: "eee", data3: "fff"},  // Second
             {data1: "ggg", data2: "hhh", data3: "iii"},  // Third
             {data1: "jjj", data2: "eee", data3: "lll"}   // Fourt
           ];
angular.forEach(data, (item, i) => {
  if (item.data2 == 'eee') {
    delete data[i].data2;   
  } 
  else if (item.data3 == 'iii') {
    delete data[i].data3;
  }
});
console.log(data);
```

Which returns:

`[{'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}, {'ddd', 'fff'}, {'ggg', 'hhh'}, {'jjj, 'lll'}]`

A working demonstration is at this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0aaud5kx/). Though your **OR ( || )** expression does indeed "work", it's not exactly in the way you intended simply because `splice` is being used to remove *an object* instead of *an item*. Thus, we have to change our logic a bit.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented your code is not working because when looping throught the array, if you remove an item, the next item will place in the removed item index, index increases in one, and this item will be never evaluated.

```js
var data = [
  {data1: "aaa", data2: "bbb", data3: "ccc"},  // First
  {data1: "ddd", data2: "eee", data3: "fff"},  // Second
  {data1: "ggg", data2: "hhh", data3: "iii"},  // Third
  {data1: "jjj", data2: "eee", data3: "lll"}   // Fourth
];

// Won't work
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  var item = data [i];
  if (item.data2 == 'eee' || item.data3 == 'iii') {
    data.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
console.log(data);
```

One solution is to loop in reverse mode. In that case removing a item will not affect the next item.

```js
var data = [
  {data1: "aaa", data2: "bbb", data3: "ccc"},  // First
  {data1: "ddd", data2: "eee", data3: "fff"},  // Second
  {data1: "ggg", data2: "hhh", data3: "iii"},  // Third
  {data1: "jjj", data2: "eee", data3: "lll"}   // Fourth
];

for(var i = data.length -1; i >= 0; i--)
  if (data[i].data2 == 'eee' || data[i].data3 == 'iii')
    data.splice(i, 1);

console.log(data);
```

If you want to keep a forEach loop style you can do your own `forEachReverse` :

```js
Array.prototype.forEachReverse = function (callback){ 
  var arr = this;
  for(var i = arr.length -1; i >= 0; i--) 
   callback(arr[i], i, arr);
};


var data = [
  {data1: "aaa", data2: "bbb", data3: "ccc"},  // First
  {data1: "ddd", data2: "eee", data3: "fff"},  // Second
  {data1: "ggg", data2: "hhh", data3: "iii"},  // Third
  {data1: "jjj", data2: "eee", data3: "lll"}   // Fourth
];

data.forEachReverse((item, i)=>{
  if (item.data2 == 'eee' || item.data3 == 'iii') {
    data.splice(i, 1);
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

As other answer suggested `filter` is cleaner and will filter your list with a condition.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation!! The problem I have posted here was actually simplified version of code. So today, I have tried all solutions everyone taught me, on the "real" code. And as you pointed out, in my real code, the items in the loop never evaluated, since I actually been deleting its own array. I've also traced every part of your code too. With idea from your solution, everything is now in where I've been wanted. Thank you!!

Comment: You're wellcome!! =)