# Bug when removing array element

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I remove an array element with the code below it removes all the elements from that array. I was wonder what I am doing wrong? Please don't hate if it's a stupid mistake, because I am a new coder.

```html
//key array
keys: [{
  x: 300,
  y: 300,
  w: 20,
  h: 20
}, {
  x: 300,
  y: 230,
  w: 20,
  h: 20
}]

//delete key if collision is detected
for (i = 0; i < level.keys.length; i++) {
  if (collectKey(p, level.keys[i])) {
    if (level.keys.length > -1) {
      level.keys.splice(0)
      console.log("Collected Key")
      console.log(level.keys.length + " keys left")
    }
  }
}


// detect collision
if (level.keys.length > -1) {
  function collectKey(e1, e3) {
    var e2 = {
      x: e3.x + 20,
      y: e3.y + 20,
      w: e3.w + 15,
      h: e3.h + 15
    }
    if (e1.x < (e2.x - x + e2.w) && (e1.x + e1.w) > e2.x - x && e1.y - vy < (e2.y - y + e2.h) && (e1.y - vy + e1.h) > e2.y - y) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
} else {
  //openDoor();
}
```

This code will detect if I am inside a key then if so it will delete that key.

Someone wanted all of the code

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">


  var game = {
   levels:[
    {
     name:"Level 1",
     tiles:[

      //List background tiles
      {x:300,y:300,w:600,h:600,solid:false,color:"#EEEEEE"},

      //List solid forground tiles
      {x:0,y:400,w:500,h:500,solid:true,color:"#CECECE"},
      {x:300,y:300,w:600,h:1,solid:true,color:"#CECECE"},
     ],
     entities:[
      {}
     ],
     keys:[
      {x:300,y:300,w:20,h:20},
      {x:300,y:230,w:20,h:20}
     ]
    },
    {
     name:"Level 2",
     tiles:[
      {}
     ],
     entities:[
      {}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <style>
  body{
   text-align: center;
  }

  #game{
   background-color: white; 
   border: 1px solid black;
   display: inline;
  }
 </style>

 <h1 style="color:#123456;">
  The Game
 </h1>
 <br>
 <body style="background-color:lightgrey;">
 <canvas text-align="center" id="game" width=500px height=500px> 
 </canvas>
 </body>
 <br>
 <h5>
  This is a game I created. Learned most of the code from Accidental games on youtube.
 </h5>
 <script type="text/javascript">


  g = document.getElementById("game");
  g = g.getContext("2d")
  console.log("loaded")
  var MAXSPEED = 5;
  var MAXTERMINALVEL = 8;
  var GRAVITY = 1;
  var x = 0;
  var y = 0;
  var vx = 0;
  var vy = 0;
  var levelNo = 0;
  var level = game.levels[levelNo]
  var canFall = true
  var keymap = []
  var p = {x:240,y:240,w:20,h:20}
  console.log(level.tiles[0].color);
  var map = {65: false, 32: false, 68: false}
  $("body").bind('keydown',function(e){
   if(e.keyCode in map){
    map[e.keyCode] = true
    if(map[68] && map[69] && map[32]){

    }
   }

  }).keyup(function(e){
   if(e.keyCode in map){
    map[e.keyCode] = false;
   }
  });

  var main = setInterval(function(){
   document.getElementById("game").height += 0;
   if(levelNo > -1){
    if(map[65]){
     if(vx<MAXSPEED){
      vx++
     }
    }
    if(map[68]){
     if(vx>-MAXSPEED){
      vx--
     }
    }
    if(map[32] && canFall==false){
     vy+=20
    }


    if(vx<0){
     vx+=0.25
    }

    if(vx>0){
     vx-=0.25
    }
    canFall = true;
    for(i=0;i<level.tiles.length;i++){
     if(isTouchingFloor(p,level.tiles[i])){
      vy = 0;
      canFall = false;
     }
     if(isTouchingWall(p,level.tiles[i])){
      vx=0
     }
    }

    for(i=0;i<level.keys.length;i++){
     if(level.keys.filter(collectKey)
    }

    if(canFall && vy>-MAXTERMINALVEL){
     vy-=GRAVITY
    }

    y-=vy
    x-=vx



    for(i=0;i<level.tiles.length;i++){
     g.fillStyle = level.tiles[i].color;
     g.fillRect(level.tiles[i].x-x,level.tiles[i].y-y,level.tiles[i].w,level.tiles[i].h);
    }

    for(i=0;i<level.keys.length;i++){
     g.fillStyle = "#ff9900"
     g.fillRect(level.keys[i].x-x+20,level.keys[i].y-y+20,40,40)
    }

    g.fillStyle = "#000000"
    g.fillRect(240,240,20,20);
    g.fillStyle = "#404040"
    g.font = "20px Arial";
    g.fillText("X: "+x,10,25);
    g.fillText("Y: "+y,10,55);

    if(y>600){
     y=0
     x=0
    }
   }



  },17)

   function collectKey(e1, e3){
     var e2 = {x:e3.x + 20,y:e3.y + 20,w:e3.w + 15,h:e3.h + 15}
      if(!(e1.x < (e2.x-x + e2.w) && (e1.x + e1.w) > e2.x-x && e1.y-vy < (e2.y-y + e2.h) && (e1.y-vy + e1.h) > e2.y-y)){
       return true;
      }
     return false;
    }


  function isTouchingFloor(e1, e2){
   if(e2.solid == true){
    if(e1.x < (e2.x-x + e2.w) && (e1.x + e1.w) > e2.x-x && e1.y-vy < (e2.y-y + e2.h) && (e1.y-vy + e1.h) > e2.y-y){
     return true;
    }
    return false;
   }  
   return false;
  }
  function isTouchingWall(e1, e2){
   if(e2.solid == true){
    if(e1.x-(vx) < (e2.x-x + e2.w) && (e1.x-(vx) + e1.w) > e2.x-x && (e1.y-1) < (e2.y-y + e2.h) && ((e1.y-1) + e1.h) > e2.y-y){
     return true
    }
    return false
   }
   return false
  }
 </script>
</html>
```

Comment: You're mutating a collection you're iterating over. Just try to evaluate the code line by line on paper and you'll find the problem

Comment: You may take a look to answers from this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37705097/or-operator-in-angular-foreach-not-working

Comment: You should copy and paste the whole code at least. level and p aren't even defined.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp - Looks like your call to `splice(0)` should be `splice(0, 1)` instead

Comment: @user3183526 That will remove the first and second from the array. but I actually need to remove [i] from the array I changed the code to splice([i]) which does not work either.

Comment: According to the link I pasted before, `splice(0, 1)` will delete ONLY the element at array index 0. Also, you are missing many semicolons - is this through choice or because you forgot?

Comment: @user3183526 my choice. Realized it was not necessary to have them so I stopped putting them there out of laziness

Comment: @user3183526 even if that is the case I tried it and it still deleted everything

Comment: Well, you are deleting elements from the array while you are still looping over it. This causes the array accesses to be messed up.

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger. If you don't know how to use a debugger, stop everything else you are doing right now and learn. You could start by googling "devtools". Also, manipulating arrays in place with `splice` is rarely a good idea. Instead, create a new array with the elements you want, using things like `filter`.